# Angular: Catch Drag and Drop event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, drag-and-drop, event-handling, dom-events

I use angular-ui to get a list which can be sorted with "drag and drop", it works fine.

just like this(works fine):

index.html

```
<ul ui-sortable ng-model="list">
    <li ng-repeat="item in list" class="item">{{item}}</li>
</ul>
```

app.js

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.sortable']);

myapp.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"];
});
```

Now, I need to know when the list(It could be a lot of list with this behaviour) is changed, I tried `drop, dropend, drag, ...` but didn't get it.

here my code http://jsfiddle.net/9sueU/4/

I need it to work with **multiples** list like here http://jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sorting your list, angular-ui will change the array order directly. You can use `$scope.$watch` to listen to the change event of your `list` array.

```
$scope.$watch("list", function (value) {
    console.log("Changed !", value);
}, true);
```

You need to pass the third argument as `true` to force Angular to verify the change with `angular.equals` instead of a basic reference equality. Indeed, the array reference doesn't change, it's still the same array, but its content is modified so only `angular.equals` can differentiate the two.

Comment: This isn't as efficient as angular's `$watchCollection` which was designed for these kinds of scenarios, but it does indeed work

Comment: I need it to work for multiples list like here jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/1 , can I get it with '$watch' ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBesson could you edit you answer to explain how it works? for example here http://jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/1/

Comment: Excellent, I spent it all the day looking for it. But if I have `lists=[{list:["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six"]:OTHER:"OTHER"},...]` it also catch when `OTHER` is changed.

Comment: You can pass a function as the first parameter of $watch to return the elements needed to be watched by AngularJS, here is a working example : http://jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/4/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch the collection for changes.  Angular will let you know even if the order has changed

```
$scope.$watchCollection('list', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    // DO something
});
```

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/)

Comment: looks nice, but I need to work for multiples list, something like here http://jsfiddle.net/b5nqd/1/

Comment: Well this is a different scenario now.  You are dealing with multiple collections, so you need to watch each collection separately.  Try using `angular.forEach` and for each array in your main list, watch that collection.  Or as Besson suggested in his answer, try using the `true` as the 3rd parameter on a normal $watch.  (It will slow things down if the data is huge.)

Comment: angular.forEach ? how do I use it? could you edit your answer to explain it?